# Finding direction of a ball after collision in cartesian coordinate system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, collision

In elastic collision of ball to wall along x axis
m*V<sub>ix</sub>=m*V<sub>fx</sub>
as velocity of wall is 0 before and after collision thus
V<sub>ix</sub>=V<sub>fx</sub>   ......eq(1)
Kinetic Energy is conserved so
m*V<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> =  m*V<sub>f</sub><sup>2</sup>
(V<sub>ix</sub><sup>2</sup> + V<sub>iy</sub><sup>2</sup>)= (V<sub>fx</sub><sup>2</sup> + V<sub>fy</sub><sup>2</sup>)
According to equation 1
V<sub>fy</sub><sup>2</sup> = V<sub>iy</sub><sup>2</sup>
How do I conclude if V<sub>iy</sub>=-V<sub>fy</sub> or V<sub>iy</sub>=V<sub>iy</sub>?
same is true for x component. 
As both equations hold true in different quadrant.

if ball collides with a wall along y axis at origin with vector along the line (4,-4) (3,-3)...(x,-y) after collision ball will move along line (1,1)(2,2)..(4,4)..(x,y) magnitude is same but direction of y is changed.

if ball collides with a wall along x axis at origin with vector along the line (4,4) (3,3)...(x,y) after collision ball will move along line (-1,1)(-2,2)..(-4,4)..(-x,y) magnitude is same but direction of x is changed in this case.

I know I can find direction of y based on :-
 as V<sub>iy</sub>|=|V<sub>fy</sub>| and  |V<sub>ix</sub>|=|V<sub>fx</sub>|
if  V<sub>ix</sub>=V<sub>fx</sub>  then V<sub>iy</sub>=-V<sub>fy</sub> if it was not then ball will pass through the wall.
But my problem is I don't want to derive this based on logic or observation  but using maths or physics.

Comment: You say that it is an inelastic collision, however afterwards you say kenetic energy is conserved. This is a contradiction. And rebember momentum is conserved in a closed system, however the ball interacts with wall and therefore is not closed.

Comment: @fibonatic I mean elastic collision where kinetic energy is conserved

Comment: I am assuming your "ball" is not rolling? And that you have a typo - you meant "How do I conclude if $V_{iy}=-V_{fy}$ or  $V_{iy}=+V_{fy}$, I assume? If that assumption is correct, the answer is "if your velocity didn't change, you must have gone through the wall..."

Comment: ball is not rolling and it collides with wall along y axis at origin with vector along the line (4,-4) (3,-3)...(x,-y) after collision ball will move along line (1,1)(2,2)..(4,4)..(x,y) magnitude is same but direction of y is changed

Comment: @Floris it not 1D problem so its totally possible velocity along one axis remains same

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the solution can be found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-Dimensional_Collision_With_Two_Moving_Objects

Comment: @saurabh I know that - but as stated if the wall is along the X direction then the Y component must change or you go through the wall. So look at the wall: the direction it is pointing tells you which sign to change.

Comment: Closing this seems harsh. The question is how we know the relation between the initial and final values of $v_y$ and this seems to me to fit the requirement of asking about a concept.

Comment: Hi saurabh. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks for giving pointer, I understand the policy of community and I believe this is a conceptual question rather than simple problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

In inelastic collisions, kinetic energy is not conserved, so I'm going to assume you mean a totally elastic collision since you say energy is conserved. O.K, so when the ball hits the wall, the speed of the wall before and after is 0, so that means the kinetic energy of the ball is conserved and thus the magnitude of the velocity is the same before and after for the ball, however we are dealing with vectors. What is the direction of the ball after the collision?

Well if the ball hits at an angle perpendicular to the wall, the resulting velocity vector will have to be in the opposite direction as the initial velocity vector.

If it hits at an angle that is not 90 degrees, then you just break the velocity vector down into its components and after analysing the velocity vectors of the ball before and after, you will see that the velocity component perpendicular to the wall is in the negative direction from the initial one, while the other is parallel to the initial velocity vector.

This agrees with the question in which the ball hits head on, as it only has one velocity vector component - and its perpendicular to the wall.

Comment: that's the only way out to determine direction? using vectors? I was curious if conservation equations can give me the direction?

Comment: @saurabh Well, in this case you would use conservation of momentum, but in order to get the correct answer you need to realize that the components of certain velocities may be pointing in the opposite direction from the initial velocity, (This is not always the case with inelastic collisions) such as billiard balls striking each other at an angle. This is why it is never a bad idea to draw system diagrams for before and after the collisions.